# What is the recommended CORS configuration of hosting Javascript on S3/CF?

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

I have seen the answers to similar questions but I am wondering that in 2017 what is the best way of configure CORS for S3/CF if I would like to restrict the legitimate access to *.domain.tld. The Javascript is loading from CF and renders a web app using Ajax requests to api.domain.tld.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*.domain.tld</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>OPTIONS</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Is there anything else I could add to improve on the CORS settings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following are the general rules for making a CORS configuration:

```
1)A valid CORS configuration consists of 0 to 100 CORS rules.
2)Each rule must include at least one origin.
3)An origin may contain at most one wildcard *
4)Each rule must include at least one method.
5)The supported methods are: GET, HEAD, PUT, POST, DELETE.
6)Each rule may contain an identifying string of up to 255 characters.
7)Each rule may specify zero or more allowed request headers (which the client may include in the request).
8)Each rule may specify zero or more exposed response headers (which are sent back from the server to the client).
9)Each rule may specify a cache validity time of zero or more seconds. If not included, the client should supply their own default.
```

Recently I worked with one of JS/CF project and here is my CORS Configuration.

```
<CORSConfiguration>
<CORSRule>
    <ID>example.com: Allow PUT & POST with AWS S3 JS
    SDK</ID>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>Origin</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-Length</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-Type</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-MD5</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>X-Amz-User-Agent</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>X-Amz-Date</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>1800</MaxAgeSeconds>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <ID>example.com: Allow GET with AWS S3 JS SDK</ID>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>1800</MaxAgeSeconds>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

More details you can find [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216201557-How-to-setup-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-CORS-on-DreamObjects)

Thanks