# AllowedHeader option in S3 CORS with CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

My use case is simple, I have static files (JS, images) in S3 that I want to share to multiple origins via CloudFront CDN.

I only want to publicly allow `GET` from S3 and my actual configuration is the following:

```xml
<CORSRule>
    <ID>BucketCORSRules</ID>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3600</MaxAgeSeconds>
</CORSRule>
```

Everything works nicely except that sometimes I randomly get a `"no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present"` error when I put new S3 objects.

My question is about `AllowedHeader`.

I've read everywhere ([here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19939041/1480391), [again on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24459590/1480391) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41668608/1480391) and [here on AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors)) that `AllowedHeader` should be set to `*` or `Authorization`, but why?

Shouldn't this CORS configuration be working with [CORS simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests) without any `AllowedHeader`? What could possibly drive to random `"no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present"` errors?

> The `AllowedHeader` element specifies which headers are allowed in a
> preflight request through the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header.
> Each header name in the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header must
> match a corresponding entry in the rule. Amazon S3 will send only the
> allowed headers in a response that were requested. For a sample list
> of headers that can be used in requests to Amazon S3, go to [Common
> Request Headers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonRequestHeaders.html) in the Amazon Simple Storage Service API Reference
> guide.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#cors-allowed-headers

Comment: Can you capture the request and response of one of these failed requests?  I wonder if you aren't encountering a [timing issue with CloudFront](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35541525/1695906) that can be resolved by setting the error caching minimum ttl for 403/404 errors to `0`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot `AllowedHeader` = request headers, and `ExposeHeader` = response headers

Comment: I am not sure what I was thinking.  You are of course, correct.  Removed the comment.

Comment: Did you clarify when and why `AllowedHeader` is needed? I've found the documentation about it very confusing. Another way to phrase the question would be: *which headers should be allowed in a preflight request? And when/why?*