# Amazon S3 - Accessing Presigned URLs

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have generated a presigned s3 url. When trying to access it from the JS code, I am getting error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" and my bucket cors configuration was

```
<CORSConfiguration>
  <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
   <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Based on few resources I have found online like - [CORS. Presigned URL. S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47689489/cors-presigned-url-s3) etc
I have changed the cors configuration to

```
    <CORSConfiguration>
      <CORSRule>
       <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
       <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
       <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
       <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
      </CORSRule>
    </CORSConfiguration>
```

and it worked and I am able to access the url through the js code. But I am trying to understand if there are any security implications for changing this tag from Authorization to *.

Please let me know.

Comment: This is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664431/what-is-the-recommended-cors-configuration-of-hosting-javascript-on-s3-cf

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on how you plan to use the pre-signed url.

- If it is going to be used by a web application/server to access an s3 resource temporarily, the CORS `AllowedOrigin` should be restricted to the domain of the application that will be requesting the resource. Generally, this CORS configuration (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) has the greatest security impact. See [this](http://blog.securelayer7.net/owasp-top-10-security-misconfiguration-5-cors-vulnerability-patch/) or [this](https://www.acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/insecure-cors-configuration).

  You can limit it with a wildcard or specific domain:

  ```
  <AllowedOrigin>https://*.mydomain.s3.amazonaws.com</AllowedOrigin>
  ```
- If it will be requested by multiple clients (i.e an end user web browser), then you have no option but to set `<AllowedOrigin>*<AllowedOrigin>`, so this will not be the recommended approach.

If you have restricted access to only allow domains you trust, then the security implications of setting the `AllowedHeaders` to `*` is minimal.